# What does a comma separating dependent variables mean in a linear regression?

Tags: r, model, linear-regression, lm

I don't understand what a comma between dependent variable in the lm function means. The model with the comma separating the dependent variables provides a much smaller AIC when compared to the model with the + separating the dependent variables. If anyone could enlighten me that would be greatly appreciated!

I have already tried consulting the lm manual and some multiple linear regression guides.

With Comma separator

```
m15 <- lm(FAD~ mobldata$meanmarchtemp , mobldata$snowcover,
          data=mobldata)
summary(m15)
AIC(m15)
[1] 254.3559
```

vs.

with + separator

```
m9 <- lm(FAD~mobldata$snowcover + mobldata$meanmarchtemp, data = mobldata)
summary(m9)
AIC(m9)
[1] 357.9709
```

I came across this when I was building an model summary table.
Thank you again for your help!

Comment: You don't use `$` in formulas. The correct form of the second example is `lm(FAD ~ snowcover + meanmarchtemp, data = mobldata)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything after the comma would be a separate argument to `lm()`, not part of the actual regression formula. The arguments to `lm()` are `lm(formula, data, subset, ...)`, and `data` is handled as a named argument, so `snowcover` would be the `subset` argument.

Assuming `snowcover` is a logical variable, the model with the `subset` argument is being fit to only the observations where `snowcover` is `TRUE`. (if `snowcover` is not a binary variable like that, something unexpected might be happening). Because the models are being fit to different numbers of observations, the AICs won't be comparable I think.

Comment: Yeah, passing a numeric vector to `subset` looks like it includes only the rows with those indices, which makes sense but is probably not what is wanted most of the time.